# Host Blazor WebAssembly with Authentication project on windows IIS

Tags: authentication, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I just created Blazor WebAssembly with Authentication project and didn't change anything on the code then tried to host the project on windows IIS it always gives me this error when the website run:

```
("crit: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Rendering.WebAssemblyRenderer[100]
      Unhandled exception rendering component: Could not load settings from '_configuration/MyWebstieAut.Client'
      Error: Could not load settings from '_configuration/MyWebstieAut.Client'
         at a.createUserManager (http://mywebsiteaut.com/_content/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication/AuthenticationService.js:1:5887)
         at Generator.prototype.next (native code)
Microsoft.JSInterop.JSException: Could not load settings from '_configuration/MyWebstieAut.Client'
Error: Could not load settings from '_configuration/MyWebstieAut.Client'
   at a.createUserManager (http://mywebsiteaut.com/_content/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication/AuthenticationService.js:1:5887)
   at Generator.prototype.next (native code)
  at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1[TResult].get_Result () <0x21bcc70 + 0x0002c> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Microsoft.JSInterop.JSRuntimeExtensions.InvokeVoidAsyn")
```

Can you help me in this?

Thanks

program.cs:

```
 var builder = WebAssemblyHostBuilder.CreateDefault(args);
            builder.RootComponents.Add<App>("#app");
            builder.Services.AddHttpClient("{ProjectName}.ServerAPI", client => client.BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress))
                .AddHttpMessageHandler<BaseAddressAuthorizationMessageHandler>();

            // Supply HttpClient instances that include access tokens when making requests to the server project
            builder.Services.AddScoped(sp => sp.GetRequiredService<IHttpClientFactory>().CreateClient("{ProjectName}.ServerAPI"));
            builder.Services.AddApiAuthorization();

            await builder.Build().RunAsync();
```

appsettings.json:

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=aspnet-{ProjectName}.Server-A5A9DCDA-10E3-45AE-A34F-DEF0D6A04784;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true",
    "{ProjectName}ServerContextConnection": "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database={ProjectName}.Server;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "IdentityServer": {
    "Clients": {
      "{ProjectName}.Client": {
        "Profile": "IdentityServerSPA"
      },
"Key": {
  "Type": "Store",
  "StoreName": "WebHosting",
  "StoreLocation": "CurrentUser",
  "Name": "CN=MyApplication"
}
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have published the appsettings.json in your wwwroot folder.
In a WASM project the client configuration are read from that file in that location.
And you, probably, have another appsettings.json for your server project in another location (not wwwroot).

If you have chosen the *Microsoft Identity* authentication type, than you need an **appsettings.json** in your `wwwroot` folder of the Blazor Client project like this one:

```json
{
  /*
  The following identity settings need to be configured
  before the project can be successfully executed.
  For more info see https://aka.ms/dotnet-template-ms-identity-platform 
  */
  "AzureAd": {
    "Authority": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/22222222-2222-2222-2222-222222222222",
    "ClientId": "33333333-3333-3333-33333333333333333",
    "ValidateAuthority": true
  }
}
```

You also need to create a "Key" in order to allow the Identity Server to work as expected.
Info here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity-api-authorization?view=aspnetcore-5.0#example-deploy-to-a-non-azure-web-hosting-provider

For testing purpose you can modify the deployed **appsettings.json** as follow (see at *Key*):

```json
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=aspnet-TestWasmAuthIndividual.Server-D7E2935A-AF1F-4B7C-9870-1288478498E1;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "IdentityServer": {
    "Clients": {
      "TestWasmAuthIndividual.Client": {
        "Profile": "IdentityServerSPA"
      }
    },
    "Key": {
      "Type": "Development"
    }
  },
"AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

with this configuration I've deployed my **Server** project (because I've chosen *ASP.NET Core Hosted*) to a folder in the **Default Web Site** in IIS.
Remember to change you're `<base href...` in *index.html* if you publish in a subfolder.

Comment: I moved appsetings.json file to wwwroot and made sure there is one  appsetings.json file in the publish folder, but didn't work

Comment: Could you please share your Program.cs (Client) and your appsettings.json (ClientI) ?

Comment: I added them in the question

Comment: The appsettings.json you added to the answer is for the __Blazor Server__ project. You need another one for the __Blazor Client__. I've added some information to my answer.

Comment: I'm using individual accounts type and hosting with IIS

Comment: If u can check my edit on the question. I added the key is this correct? also the file in the server if I deleted it from the server the project will not work.

Comment: For testing purpose is better that you add the Key like in my example using "Development" (if you're deploying into your local IIS instance). In case you're deploying to an instance of IIS on another computer/server you need to create a certificate and load it into the IIS configuration.